# POST the values of several html <input type='button'>

Tags: javascript, html, post

I have a html form with several `<input type='button' value='1'>` buttons. Each button has a predefined value of '1'.
Example:
I have two buttons next to each other, one represents morning and one represents afternoon. I want the user to chose either of them, or both, by clicking the buttons. A javascript function then changes the value and the background colour of each button through `<input type='button'... onclick=change(this) >` and the JS function `function change(button) { button.value='2';button.style.background='red'}`

This is all working fine and I see all buttons with the respective colours and values, depending on whether the user clicked them or not. Now I have a final submit button in the form and I need to get the values of each button.

I tried `<input type='button' ... name='buttons[]'>` to later get an array from $_POST['buttons'], but type='button' does not seem to POST any values. I also tried the `<button....>` tags, no success.
Also I DO NOT want each button to be of `type=submit`.

What is the best way to get  all button values after the user clicks the final submit button of the form ?

Thanks a lot

p.s. I have already tried to create a hidden input field `<input name='hid[]' type='hidden'>` and then in the JS function `{var hid=document.getElementById('hidid'); hid.value='2';}` but this does not seem to add the value to the POST array hid[]

Here's the full code:

HTML: -

```
<form class='productform' method='post' id='resform' action='viewDate.shtml'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name='buttons[]' id='buttonid' onclick=change(this) value='1'>Morning</input>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input name='hid[]' id='buttonidhid' value='1' type='hidden'></input>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name='buttons[]' id='buttonid' onclick=change(this) value='1'>Afternoon</input>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name='hid[]' id='buttonidhid' value='1' type='hidden'></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <input type='submit' name='submitbutton' value='Save'></input>
</form>
```

Js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(button) {
    var hid=getElementById('buttonidhid');
     if(button.value=='1') {
        button.value='2';
        button.style.background='red';
        hid.value='2';
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use radio/option buttons?

Comment: it's supposed to be a time-schedule, and the user should directly see which time slots are still available or not (and can reserve a time by clicking a button and see the color change). radio buttons etc would work but i do not like the style in this case

Comment: You'll have to use hidden input fields that replicate the values.

Comment: Can I see the complete html and js code?

Comment: First of all, you can not use same **id** for multiple dom element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use radio/option buttons and do some very nice styling.

See:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/
http://www.sitepoint.com/15-jquery-radio-button-checkbox-style-plugins/
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-create-custom-radio-buttons-using-css-and-jquery.php
http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Some really nice ones:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css3_oval_switch_checkboxes/
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/07/css-buttons-tutorials-and-examples/

Along your lines:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/css-radio-button-checkbox-background/

Below taken from "Last Link":

```
/*
  Hide radio button (the round disc)
  we will use just the label to create pushbutton effect
*/
input[type=radio] {
    display:none; 
    margin:10px;
}

/*
  Change the look'n'feel of labels (which are adjacent to radiobuttons).
  Add some margin, padding to label
*/
input[type=radio] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-2px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    border-color: #ddd;
}
/*
 Change background color for label next to checked radio button
 to make it look like highlighted button
*/
input[type=radio]:checked + label { 
   background-image: none;
    background-color:#d0d0d0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I will look into this if I can't find a solution for the above !

Comment: No Problem.  Shout if you get stuck.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @LShetty Problem with CSS is there really are too many examples of variances for option buttons and is really very much a personal taste.  The links above are just or the benefit of the discussion, but can just as easily be found by searching for "funky radio/option button css", which is what I alluded to.  By the time the links are no longer valid (ALL OF THEM), new HTML and CSS Standards will be upon us.  I have, nonetheless, included code from the last link.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add a name to your buttons :

```
<input type='button' value='1' name='button1'>
```

That way, you'll be able to get the values of your buttons using `$_POST['button1']`

Comment: That only works with *submit* buttons which are used to submit the form. Not button buttons and not submit buttons which aren't the one that was clicked.